# How to install latest version of Django 1.5 using pip?

Tags: python, django, pip

I want to install django1.5x. So I tried:

```
pip install django
```

but `django1.6` gets installed.

I tried again by:

```
pip install django==1.5
```

but I got error:

```
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement django==1.5
No distributions at all found for django==1.5
Storing complete log in /home/suhail/.pip/pip.log
```

Comment: @PrashantGaur Python 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2013, 20:08:41) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2

Comment: you can directly download from link : https://www.djangoproject.com/download/1.5.5/tarball/   then run setup.py .it will be simple way

Answer (score 14):

```
pip install django=="1.5"
```

works for me

```
pip install django=="1.5"
Downloading/unpacking django==1.5
Downloading Django-1.5.tar.gz (8.0MB): 8.0MB downloaded
Running setup.py egg_info for package django
```

What version of Python are you using?

Comment: python 2.7.3, `pip install django=="1.5" doesn't worked, show the same error.

Comment: What do you get back from: pip -v install django==1.5

Answer (score 8):

Specify version as `<1.6`:

```
pip install "Django<1.6"
```

This installs *Django 1.5.5* for now.

**NOTE**: Don't forget the quotes. otherwise `<` is interpreted as redirection.

Comment: Worked for me.
`~ $ sudo pip install "Django<1.6"
  Downloading/unpacking Django<1.6
  Downloading Django-1.5.4.tar.gz (8.1MB): 8.1MB downloaded
  ...
  Successfully installed Django
Cleaning up...`

Answer (score 3):

Did you try to give the exact version number?

```
pip install django==1.5.5
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have any other version installed, first uninstall it using `pip`:

```
pip uninstall django
```

next install the desired version:

```
pip install django==1.5x  #or any version of choice
```

Answer (score 0):

I just got the same error when trying to upgrade from 1.5.5 to 1.6. By-passing our proxy server by unchecking the proxy configuration on IE's Internet Options > Connections > LAN Settings > Proxy Server. It looks like our proxy blocks the connection port of pip.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I guess it is a pip bug, that I can not install a number extension for a specific version, well sometimes even without a specific version. I doubt sometimes it is due to internet connection, as I had several times time out problem. I would try to use this pip usage to install my target version:

```
pip install http://my.package.repo/SomePackage-1.0.4.zip
```